# Django multiprocessing database concurrency

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multiprocessing

I am stuck with the following database concurrency problem.

I am building a django webapp using psycopg2 to comunicate with a PostgreSQL database. The queries are run from different processes.

In order to lock rows all the queries are inside a transaction atomic block.

```
   with transaction.atomic():
       self.analysis_obj = Analysis.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=self.analysis_id)
```

However sometimes I get random error like:

- 'no results to fetch',
- 'pop from empty list',
- 'error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq'.

Any idea to deal with this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For whom is interested I found a solution.

When using multiprocessing in Python, you should close all connection every time a process is spawned.

```
from django.db import connection
connection.close()
```

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?